# Draw trendline from start of day to end of day using specific start price and close price

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

Can someone please help me modify below code to use market close time instead of bar_index+1 which can also help me omit openLine.set line as well

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay = true)
newDay = ta.change(time('D'))
var line openLine = na
if newDay
    openLine := line.new(bar_index, 2534.05, bar_index+1, 2481.90)
openLine.set_x2(bar_index)
```

In above code instead of bar_index+1 i want to specify end of day time for eg:- indian market close at 15:25pm so i can avoid openLine.set as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the timestamp of the close bar using the `timestamp()` function.

```
timestamp(year, month, day, hour, minute, second) → simple int
```

Then use `xloc=xloc.bar_time` in your `line.new()` so it will use times instead of bar indices.

Then you can pass `time` to the `x1` argument and the return value of the `timestamp()` to the `x2`.